# blur() function doesn't work for textarea

Tags: jquery

I try to add textarea on the page dynamically (it works) and then I try to remove textarea on blur() event but it doesn't work

```
$(function () {
$('.edit').one('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var comment$ = $(this).parents('li').prev('li.comment-post');
    var text = comment$.text(); 
    comment$.html('<textarea name="comment-edit" class="comment-edit">' + text + '</textarea><br />');  
    $('.comment-edit').focus();
});

$('.comment-edit').blur(function(){
    alert('text');
    var text = $(this).val();
    alert(text);
    /*var comment$ = $(this).parents('li.comment-post');
    $(this).remove();
    comment$.text('text');*/
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wx85E/35/

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
$('.comment-edit').live('blur',function(){
    alert('text');
    var text = $(this).val();
    alert(text);
    /*var comment$ = $(this).parents('li.comment-post');
    $(this).remove();
    comment$.text('text');*/
});
```

I have used live because you have added 1.8.3 jquery library in fiddle.

You need to use on if you are using libraries 1.9 and further:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.comment-edit',function(){
//code
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wx85E/36/)**

Comment: You should not use live, its deprecated, use on-function istead http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Use `on` event instead

Comment: can you see that OP has added jq library 1.8.3. Live is supported in it

Comment: but why `$('.comment-edit').on('blur',function(){});` or `$('.comment-edit').blur(function(){});` doesn't work?

Comment: @truslivii.lev: it is good practice to use latest libraries. So you might wanna move on with second approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    $('.edit').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var comment$ = $(this).parents('li').prev('li.comment-post');
        var text = comment$.text(); 
        if($('.comment-edit').length){
            $('.comment-edit').show();
        }
        else{
        comment$.html('<textarea name="comment-edit" class="comment-edit">' + text + '</textarea><br />');
        }
        $('.comment-edit').blur(function(){

           var text = $(this).val();
           comment$.text(text);
            /*var comment$ = $(this).parents('li.comment-post');*/
            $('.comment-edit').hide();/*
            comment$.text('text');*/
        });
        $('.comment-edit').focus();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle reference](http://jsfiddle.net/gokuldahal/D2Unk/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are binding that textarea live:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.comment-edit',function(){
        alert('text');
        var text = $(this).val();
        alert(text);
    });
```

Comment: no, `on()` doesn't work with jquery1.8.3, `on()` starts work only in 1.9. I get the explanation above ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind the blur event to the text-area before the text-area is created. Try this fork:

http://goo.gl/fU0DVn